# Execute code only if one of the if statements ran

Tags: java, if-statement

Take a look at this example code.

```
boolean check = false;

if (condition) {
    do x;
    check = true;
}
else  if (condition2) {
    do y;
    check = true;
}
else if (condition3) {
    do z;
    check = true;
}

if (check) {
    do a;
} else {
    do b;
}
```

There has to be a better way to do this than a boolean variable, no? I mean it works, but it looks kind of messy to me.

Comment: Well, instead of each `check = true;` you can `do a;`. Just add another `else` to handle `do b;`. But honestly this would be against DRY principle so what you have seems better.

Comment: `if (condition || condition2 || condition3) {do a;} else { do b;}`

Comment: In this exact scenario, this would likely be the cleanest. Either this or `if (condition || condition2 || condition3)`, or something to that effect

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call it "better", but it would at least be more concise to use `if (check = condition)`, `if (check = condition2)` etc.

Comment: If you have more if-else statement I suggest you use the switch statement. switch uses a hash map. so, it will be a little bit faster than if-else. although each one as there own benefit. you have to choose based on your requirements. In if-else you can handle the order of execution on after another.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, you could put `a` in each of the `if` conditions and add a single final `else` for `b`. Like,

```
if (condition) {
    do x;
    do a;
} else if (condition2) {
    do y;
    do a;
} else if (condition3) {
    do z;
    do a;
} else {
    do b;
}
```

Comment: @JustADude It's three replicated lines, **exactly** the same number (in fact) as `check = true;` in the original. But it eliminates `check`, so it is "better" (if you could give more context on condition(s), it might be possible to use a `switch` statement and fall-through).

Answer (score 0):

You could write it this way if you prefer:

```
if (condition) {
    do x;
} else if (condition2) {
    do y;
} else if (condition3) {
    do z;
} else {
    do b;
    return;
}
do a;
```

Whether that makes sense for your context depends on what all these a, b, condition etc. actually are.

If you can't use return, you could at least reduce the number of places you're setting your boolean variable:

```
boolean check = true;
if (condition) {
    do x;
} else if (condition2) {
    do y;
} else if (condition3) {
    do z;
} else {
    do b;
    check = false;
}
if (check) {
    do a;
}
```

Comment: Using a labelled break instead of a return is a possibility for the first way (for example, if something follows all of this code, precluding a return).

Answer (score -1):

I would propose to define your business logic of actions x, y etc.. as separate classes or functional implementations of the interface `Action` with a single method `execute()`

Your codebase will be replaced with something similar:

```
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface Action {
      void execute();
    }

    Action action =
            condition1 ? () -> System.out.println("Action X") :
            condition2 ? () -> System.out.println("Action Y") : null;

    if (Objects.nonNull(action)) {
        action.execute();
        ((Action) () -> System.out.println("Action A")).execute();
    } else {
        ((Action) () -> System.out.println("Action B")).execute();
    }
```